# Error message ORA-19279: XPTY0004 received when trying to create view of XML file in PL/SQL. There are two XML tags with the same name

Tags: sql, oracle, xml-namespaces, xmltype, xmltable

I have next below XML message:

```
<Message xmlns="http://test.org">
    <Request Promotion="MULANN">
        <ExpireDate>23/10/2020 07:10</ExpireDate>
        <Entries>
            <Entry>
                <Product>
                    <Product Product="T1" />
                </Product>
                <Payment>
                    <Privacy>N</Privacy>
                </Payment>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <Product>
                    <Product Product="T2" />
                </Product>
                <Payment>
                    <Privacy>N</Privacy>
                </Payment>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <Product>
                    <Product Product="T3" />
                </Product>
                <Payment>
                    <Privacy>Y</Privacy>
                </Payment>
            </Entry>            
        </Entries>
    </Request>
</Message>
```

For this xml message, I have three times the xml tag **Privacy**

How can I get the distinct value of privacy for all of them without fetch the error?.

Now I'm using next below query that contain the error:

```
select distinct x.Promotion, x.Privacy
  from TableName a
  cross join XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES('http://test.org' AS "XML"),
                '/XML:Message' passing xmltype(xml_info) columns
                Promotion VARCHAR2(20) path 'XML:Request/@Promotion'
                Iban_TABD CHAR(1)      path 'XML:Request/XML:Entries/XML:Entry/XML:Payment/XML:Privacy')x
```

I'd like to get something like this:

```
Promotion     Privacy
MULANN           N
MULANN           Y
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the XML has multiple levels of nesting.
You solve this by chaining the XMLTABLEs.

If not all information is always available in the nested children, an outer join helps.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       promotion,
       privacy
  FROM TableName,
       XMLTABLE( XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'http://test.org'),
       '/Message' PASSING XMLTYPE(xml_info)
       COLUMNS promotion   VARCHAR2(20)   PATH 'Request/@Promotion',
               entries     XMLTYPE        PATH 'Request/Entries/Entry'
       ) x1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
       XMLTABLE( XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'http://test.org'),
       '/Entry' PASSING x1.entries
       COLUMNS privacy     VARCHAR2(1)    PATH 'Payment/Privacy'
       )) x2
       ON 1=1;
```